# Deployment of GCP's Google Functions not possible, returning an empty error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am new to GCP and just trying to work with deployment of my first Google Functions. Initially I tried to deploy the most basic default function, one that's being loaded automatically by GCP with 'Hello World'. However when deploying it deployment fails and I am returned with empty error message, id, types etc. (see below)

Deployment failure:
Build failed:

```
{
    "metrics": {},
    "error": {
        "buildpackId": "",
        "buildpackVersion": "",
        "errorType": "OK",
        "canonicalCode": "OK",
        "errorId": "",
        "errorMessage": ""
    },
    "stats": [
        {
            "buildpackId": "google.utils.archive-source",
            "buildpackVersion": "0.0.1",
            "totalDurationMs": 35,
            "userDurationMs": 35
        },
        {
            "buildpackId": "google.python.functions-framework",
            "buildpackVersion": "0.9.6",
            "totalDurationMs": 74,
            "userDurationMs": 74
        },
        {
            "buildpackId": "google.python.pip",
            "buildpackVersion": "0.9.2",
            "totalDurationMs": 7589,
            "userDurationMs": 7580
        },
        {
            "buildpackId": "google.utils.label",
            "buildpackVersion": "0.0.2",
            "totalDurationMs": 0,
            "userDurationMs": 0
        }
    ],
    "warnings": null,
    "customImage": false
}
```

Can anyone advise on what might go wrong here?

Edit: Adding source of code for refference:

```
def hello_world(request):
    """Responds to any HTTP request.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): HTTP request object.
    Returns:
        The response text or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using
        `make_response <http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.make_response>`.
    """
    request_json = request.get_json()
    if request.args and 'message' in request.args:
        return request.args.get('message')
    elif request_json and 'message' in request_json:
        return request_json['message']
    else:
        return f'Hello World!'
```

Comment: you can have logs in google cloud console to investigate and find a relevant error

Comment: `OK` is not an error... while it's entirely unclear how you deploy that. "Build failed" suggest that you don't deploy anything, but if fails before already.

Comment: @MartinZeitler at this stage I am using default settings on everything, choosing HTTP trigger, Python 3.9 as my Runtime choice. All rest is default. I notice that the message I get is showing first that google.python.pip is taking too long to execute; I tried also to preinstall and update pip, it doesn't change a thing.

Comment: @MartinWalczyński "choosing HTTP trigger" sounds as if you'd deploy with the web-based console... while "build failed" suggests that possibly source code or dependencies might be at fault. I mean, your question doesn't feature a single line of code ...check the Logs Explorer.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I added the code for reference. 

I also found identical problem online https://serverfault.com/questions/1081875/cannot-build-any-functions-with-cloud-function

Though I am not sure this is the correct way to go with this. I checked and my Organization Policy locations is allowing the location I am using in my function so it shouldn't be a problem. I want to be sure that this is the issue before I suggest any changes to my GCP admin.

Comment: Alright, upon checking the logs, this is exactly the same issue with constraints/gcp.resourceLocations ; Topic can be closed

Comment: Nice to know that you can find the root cause of the issue. It would be great if you could post the cause and solution as an answer to the question so that the community members can get help when they face similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

That code appears truncated and should look alike [this](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/create-deploy-http-python):

```
from flask import escape
import functions_framework

@functions_framework.http
def hello_world(request):
...
```

Unless annotating with `@functions_framework.http`, there is no HTTP Cloud Function.